# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ITasksLogicClass' while attempting to activate 'TaskAPI'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I was creating an API in .Net Core and I got this error, which is due to error in Dependency Injection.

Error:  `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'todoapi.Logics.ITasksLogicClass' while attempting to activate 'todoapi.Controllers.TaskAPI'`

Codes:

#### Controller>TaskAPI.cs

```
namespace todoapi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("task/v1")]
    public class TaskAPI:Controller
    {
        private readonly ITasksLogicClass _x;
       
        public TaskAPI(ITasksLogicClass x)
        {
            this._x= x;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public String Get()
        {
            return _x.Testfunc();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Logics>TaskLogic.cs

```
namespace todoapi.Logics
{
    public class TaskLogic:ITasksLogicClass
    {
        public string Testfunc()
        {
            return ("API Works Now");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Logics>TaskLogicInterface.cs

```
namespace todoapi.Logics
{
    public interface ITasksLogicClass
    {
        string Testfunc();
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please show your DI configuration. Show the registration you made for `ITasksLogicClass`.

Comment: Hi Anwesh, you should definitely show the `services.AddXXX` call (or calls) to your question, because this allows us to inspect what you are doing wrong in that registration as it is there where the problem lies. If you don't have such code, that would be the cause of your trouble. You should add `services.AddTransient<ITasksLogicClass, TaskLogic>()` to your DI configuration.

Comment: Where should I add the `services.AddTransient<ITasksLogicClass, TaskLogic>()`?

Comment: You might want to start reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) first.